# How can I get the PR reviewers email address in jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm running a jenkins job to generate a report. Post the build I wan to sent that report to the person reviewed the PR. How can I achieve this using bitbucket and jenkins. Only the reviewer should get the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such plugin to give you details of PR reviewer. [Github Pull Request Builder](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ghprb/) plugin expose a limited number of environment variable. But you can try to write simple script or command to use [Github API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#list-reviews-for-a-pull-request).

As you are using Bitbucket you can do something similar using BB API ([link](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pullrequests/%7Bpull_request_id%7D))

```
curl -X GET -u "user:pass" "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/pullrequests/{pull_request_id}" | jq '.participants[] | select(.state=="approved")| .user.display_name'
```

With above **curl** command you will get **display name** of your PR approvers. You can not fetch any users email using BB API, so if it is under your company you may create a file having display name to email mapping and source it to send emails.

Comment: OP is using BitBucket, not GitHub.

Comment: Edited my answer to include information related to BB API.